# Masking bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
c89
```

Hello,

Masking bitwise operators:

I want to mask the following:

```
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1 | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_STAR | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_POUND
```

I set the above with the following function:

```
static void g_convert2_ipm_digits(unsigned short *terminator)
{
    *terminator = SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1 | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_STAR | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_POUND;

}
```

So when a digit comes in I & (and) it to see if the pattern exists:

```
static apk_bool_t g_check_term_digit(unsigned short terminators, unsigned short digit)
{
    if(terminators & digit) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE
}
```

However, the function always returns true no matter what digit it is. Should only return true for the ones I have masked.

When I check the debugger in the above function I get the following function. However, this should not return true, as the digit that has been pressed is a 5.

```
(gdb) p terminators
$22 = 11
(gdb) p digit
$23 = 5
```

The digits I expect are defined in this enum below:

```
typedef enum
{       
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_0                                               = 0x0,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1                                               = 0x1,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_2                                               = 0x2,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_3                                               = 0x3,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_4                                               = 0x4,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_5                                               = 0x5,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_6                                               = 0x6,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_7                                               = 0x7,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_8                                               = 0x8,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_9                                               = 0x9,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_STAR                                            = 0xa,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_POUND                                           = 0xb,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_A                                               = 0xc,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_B                                               = 0xd,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_C                                               = 0xe,
        SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_D                                               = 0xf,
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: To clarify, are you checking for exact bit pattern (b'1011)? or any of the bit matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use powers two values: for example

```
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_0   = 0x01,
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1   = 0x02,
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_2   = 0x04,
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_3   = 0x08,
SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_4   = 0x10,
```

because when you apply the logical OR operation, you are merging together bitmaps of numbers:

```
R = SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1 | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_3 | SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_4
```

that is equal to (in binary):

```
R = 00010 | 01000 | 10000 => 11010
```

So later you can use the & operation to see if a specific value is true:

```
R & SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_3 => true
```

because

```
11010 & 01000 => 01000 != 0 => true
```

Comment: +1. This is good, but you can't have an actual value that you want to detect (the digit 0) have a mask value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

The value for e.g. `SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_3` have *two* bits set. Bits zero and one. What you are doing is not making a bitmask in the sense you expect. It seems that you should use bit-shift as well:

```
*terminator = (1 << SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_1) |
              (1 << SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_STAR) |
              (1 << SIGNAL_ID_EVENT_DTMF_POUND);
```

Then do the same with `digit` when masking:

```
if (terminators & (1 << digit)) { ... }
```